# Disable Grammarly on Wordpress Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've found that Grammarly is interfering with the usability of the forms on our website.

I've read that the following attribute on all input fields would fix this issue and prevent Grammarly from working:

```
    data-gramm_editor="false"
```

My question is, can this be applied universally with custom jQuery/Javascript to ensure that every text input area on the website has this attribute, rather than applying it manually to all forms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` to add attributes on `input`, `textarea` and `editable divs`

```
$( "input,textarea,div[contenteditable=true]" ).attr( "data-gramm_editor", "false" );
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $("input,textarea,div[contenteditable=true]").attr("data-gramm_editor", "false");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

The correct attribute is:

```html
data-enable-grammarly="false"
```

I cannot locate the official documentation, but I have just been trying to disable Grammarly myself, and this is the only one that worked.